# How to get timestamp in ISO 8601 format with timezone in php

Tags: php, date, timestamp

Based on the [wix documentation](http://dev.wix.com/docs/display/DRAF/Working+with+the+Wix+RESTful+API), **2014-04-16T11:16:27.930Z** is a timestamp in **ISO 8601** format with a timezone.
A quick research reveals that the timestamp in **ISO 8601** displays the timezone with +time_interval (for instance +00:00)

I tried date('c') which displays: 2014-04-16T06:23:31+00:00

Could anyone tell me how to display timestamp in **2014-04-16T11:16:27.930Z** rather than **2014-04-16T06:23:31+00:00**

Comment: You could just build that yourself using `date()` if all else fails right?

Comment: True, but how to get the timezone in this format 27.930Z in the timestamp?Thanks

Comment: Istn't 930Z the timezone definition?
> Time zones in ISO 8601 are represented as local time (with the location unspecified), as UTC, or as an offset from UTC.

Comment: So i thought it would be `2014-04-16T11:16:27` representing the time with seconds and miliseconds and `930Z` is the offset from the UTC.

Comment: Based on your comment, I guess I need to look for the offset from UTC. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Wikipedia says: *If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".*

Comment: Just do `gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z');`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Considering the Wikipedia Article on [ISO_8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) the UTC Offset can be defined as "Year-Month-Day Hour:Minutes:Seconds.ZoneDesignator".

The PHP date method defines the parameter Z as

> Z Timezone offset in seconds. The offset for timezones west of UTC is always negative, and for those east of UTC is always positive.

So assuming the offset mentioned in the wikipedia article is in seconds, you could create your own `ISO 8601` using date. Example given for current server time/date:

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.Z\Z', time());
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments by @AndrewIsOffline, since [PHP5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), using 'c' will also give you the ISO 8601 Date:

```
date('c', time());
```

Comment: Bit old, but since PHP 5 just using 'c' as the date format will give the full ISO 8601 formatted time.