# How to convert timestamp into iso-8601 and also UTC together in php?

Tags: php

I am not sure how to convert timestamp into `ISO-8601` and also apply `UTC`.
 However, I am looking for following output:
`2017-09-23T01:08:36.6437128Z`  ( Format = ISO-8601. Timezone = UTC)

I have tried couple of ways to get this but I am not getting it so anyone know how to get this. As this must be very quick and easy fix but I am missing something and that's the reason I am not getting this output.

Any help would be appreciated:)
Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: I looked at that and I found answer from this link on stackoverflow(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108262/how-to-get-timestamp-in-iso-8601-format-with-timezone-in-php) but still I am not so sure that what will be the right way to do this:

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your desired format is not [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant because you're including microseconds.

Use [`date_default_timezone_set`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to get UTC and [`date`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to easily format a timestamp.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/aRKqi

```
$timestamp = 1506086214;

// set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// ISO 8601 (does NOT include microseconds)
echo date("c", $timestamp) . PHP_EOL;

// custom format e.g. 2017-09-23T01:08:36.6437128Z
echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z", $timestamp) . PHP_EOL;
```

> ```
> 2017-09-22T13:16:54+00:00
> 2017-09-22T13:16:54.000000Z
> ```